# "Markdown editing help" button in the question asking view is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, firefox

Just posted a bug report, and found another one :p

[image]

(lame hand-drawn cursor coz windows doesn't capture the real cursor)

Oh yeah, I'm on Firefox.

Comment: It's looks fine in Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.115 m, but I can reproduce in Firefox 35.0.1 and 36.0 .

Comment: Did exactly the same, was posting a bug and found this!

Comment: Repro'd in Chrome 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment issue of the **Markdown Editing Help** icon in the Firefox browser is fixed.

I have verified the alignment issue in Firefox `49.0.1`.

The recent screenshot in Firefox for your reference:

> [image: Icon placed correctly]

When click on the icon the help menu too aligned correctly. Previously it too cause the issue. [Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271831/312043)

> [image: When click on the Icon]

Comment: yea looks like it's fixed now

Answer (score 3):

It's been more than a year since this was posted, but The bug is still here

I'm running Firefox version 45.0.2, and I also see the formatting issue

[image]

Comment: I was able to repro in Firefox 45.0.2 like you, but was unable to repro in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when using Firefox (I'm using v36), the HTML of the list element containing the help icon looks like this

```
<li ... style="right: 0px; left: 639px;" id="wmd-help-button" ...>
```

Now, there is no `left: 639px;` when I use Chrome 41 and IE 11. Removing `left: 639px;` seems to fix this placement issue.