# Markdown Editing Help icon alignment issue in Firefox

Tags: bug, design, markdown, firefox

I see an alignment issue with the **Markdown Editing Help** icon and its relevant help properties in the Firefox browser.

Firefox version: 43.0.2

But the same is properly aligned in Chrome and IE 10.

Screenshot for your reference:

> [image: Without click the icon]

After clicked the icon the help properties are not aligned properly.

> [image: After clicked the icon]

Comment: I could've sworn someone was supposed to fix this. :P

Comment: Fine and thanks for the response.